# How to create a numpy array with a random entries that exclude one element in each index?

Tags: python, numpy, random, numpy-ndarray

I have an array `val` of possible values (ex. `val = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`) and an array `A` (possibly very long list) of selected values (ex. `A = [2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, ... , 2, 3, 1, 0, 4]`)

Now I want to create an array `B` of the same length as `A` such that `A[i]` is different than `B[i]` for each `i` and entries in `B` are selected randomly. How to do it efficiently using numpy?

Comment: One way to do it is to do `p=np.random.permutation(len(A))` and then `B=A[p]`. This does not gurantee `A[i] != B[i]` for each `i` though.

Comment: `A[i]!=B[i]` is essential in my case

Comment: Would `val` always be numbers in sequence `0 to n` with sequential numbers?

Comment: @Divakar In fact they could be arrays as well, however the solutions with numbers would suffice.

Comment: More specifically my question was would those numbers always be in sequence or could you have something like `[0,1,4,5,6,8,9]` for `val`?

Comment: @Divakar They are in sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method would be drawing the difference between A and B modulo n where n is the number of possible outcomes. A[i] != B[i] means that this difference is not zero, hence we draw from 1,...,n-1:

```
n,N = 10,100
A = np.random.randint(0,n,N)

D = np.random.randint(1,n,N)
B = (A-D)%n
```

Update: while arguably elegant this solution is not the fastest. We could save some time by replacing the (slow) modulo operator with just testing for negative values and adding n to them.

In this form this solution starts looking quite similar to @Divakar's: two blocks of possible values, one needs to be shifted.

But we can do better: instead of shifting on average half the values we can instead swap them out only if A[i] == B[i]. As this is expected to happen rarely unless the list of permissible values is very short, the code runs faster:

```
B = np.random.randint(1,n,N)
B[B==A] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat wasteful as it creates a temporary list for every item in `A` but otherwise fullfills your requirements:

```
from random import choice


val = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
A = [2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 4]

val = set(val)
B = [choice(list(val - {x})) for x in A]
print(B) # -> [4, 2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 5, 5, 4, 1]
```

In a nutshell:

What happens is that `val` is converted to a `set` from which the *current* item in `A` gets removed. Consequently, an item is chosen at random from this resulting subset and gets added to `B`.

---

You can also test it with:

```
print(all(x!=y for x, y in zip(A, B)))
```

which of course returns `True`

---

Finally, note that the approach above *only works with hashable items*. So if you might have something like `val = [[1, 2], [2, 3], ..]` for example you will run into problems.

Comment: @JohanC I am not sure I agree to that. That being said, I do believe that there are `numpy`-based solutions that could be much faster

Answer (score 1):

Here's one vectorized way -

```
def randnum_excludeone(A, val):
    n = val[-1]
    idx = np.random.randint(0,n,len(A))
    idx[idx>=A] += 1
    return idx
```

The idea is we generate random integers for each entry in `A` covering the entire length of `val` minus `1`. Then, we add in `1` if the current random number generated is same or greater than current `A` element, otherwise we keep it. Thus, for any random number generated that's lesser than current `A` number, we keep it. Otherwise, with `1` addition, we will offset from the current `A` number. That's our final output - `idx`.

Let's verify the random-ness and make sure it's uniform across non-A elements -

```
In [42]: A
Out[42]: array([2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 4])

In [43]: val
Out[43]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [44]: c = np.array([randnum_excludeone(A, val) for _ in range(10000)])

In [45]: [np.bincount(i) for i in c.T]
Out[45]: 
[array([2013, 2018,    0, 2056, 1933, 1980]),
 array([2018, 1985, 2066,    0, 1922, 2009]),
 array([2032,    0, 1966, 1975, 2040, 1987]),
 array([   0, 2076, 1986, 1931, 2013, 1994]),
 array([2029, 1943,    0, 1960, 2100, 1968]),
 array([2028,    0, 2048, 2031, 1929, 1964]),
 array([2046, 2065,    0, 1990, 1940, 1959]),
 array([2040, 2003, 1935,    0, 2045, 1977]),
 array([2008,    0, 2011, 2030, 1937, 2014]),
 array([   0, 2000, 2015, 1983, 2023, 1979]),
 array([2075, 1995, 1987, 1948,    0, 1995])]
```

**Benchmarking on large arrays**

Other vectorized approach(es) :

```
# @Paul Panzer's solution
def pp(A, val):
    n,N = val[-1]+1,len(A)    
    D = np.random.randint(1,n,N)
    B = (A-D)%n
    return B
```

Timing results -

```
In [66]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: A = np.random.randint(0,6,100000)

In [67]: %timeit pp(A,val)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.11 ms per loop

In [68]: %timeit randnum_excludeone(A, val)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.53 ms per loop

In [69]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: A = np.random.randint(0,6,1000000)

In [70]: %timeit pp(A,val)
10 loops, best of 3: 39.9 ms per loop

In [71]: %timeit randnum_excludeone(A, val)
10 loops, best of 3: 25.9 ms per loop
```

Extending the range of `val` to `10` -

```
In [60]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: A = np.random.randint(0,10,1000000)

In [61]: %timeit pp(A,val)
10 loops, best of 3: 31.2 ms per loop

In [62]: %timeit randnum_excludeone(A, val)
10 loops, best of 3: 23.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: @JohanC No, it's independent of `A`'s distribution. `B` as per question's requirement has to be different from `A`, which this does. Did I misunderstand your query?

Comment: Avoiding the logical indexing and instead simply adding the mask to idx seems a few percent faster. In fact, with this change your and my approach are neck-and-neck on my laptop ;-)

Comment: @PaulPanzer The existing one seems to be better by a good margin. What's your setup?

Comment: @PaulPanzer And with simply adding mask seems to be 2x+ better.

Comment: @Divakar you are right, I only tested on a small (100 entry) example, your approach scales a bit better. But my point about avoiding the fancy indexing still stands. On my laptop, returning idx + (idx>=a) gives a 25% speedup on the 1,000,000 array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. `B` first gets a random shuffle of `A`. Then, all the values where `A` and `B` overlap get shuffled. In the special case where all the overlapping elements have the same value, they get swapped with random good values.

Interesting on this approach is that it also works when there `A` only contains a very limited set of different values. Unlike other approaches, `B`is an exact shuffle of `A`, so it also works when `A` doesn't have a uniform distribution. Also, `B` is a completely random shuffle except for the requirement of being different at equal indices.

```py
import random
N = 10000
A = [random.randrange(0,6) for _ in range(N)]
B = a.copy()
random.shuffle(b)
print(A)
print(B)

while True:
    equal_vals = {i for i,j in zip(A, B) if i == j}
    print(len(equal_vals), equal_vals)
    if len(equal_vals) == 0:  # finished, no equal values on same positions
        break
    else:
        equal_ind = [k for k, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(A, B)) if i == j]
        # create a list of indices where A and B are equal
        random.shuffle(equal_ind)  # as the list was ordened, shuffle it to get a random order

        if len(equal_vals) == 1:  # special case, all equal indices have the same value
            special_val = equal_vals.pop()
            # find all the indices where the special_val could be placed without problems
            good_ind = [k for k,(i,j) in enumerate(zip(A, B)) if i != special_val and j != special_val]
            if len(good_ind) < len(equal_ind):
                print("problem: there are too many equal values in list A")
            else:
                # swap each bad index with a random good index
                chosen_ind = random.sample(good_ind, len(equal_ind))
                for k1, k2 in zip(equal_ind, chosen_ind):
                    b[k1], b[k2] = b[k2], b[k1]  # swap
            break
        elif len(equal_vals) >= 2:

            # permute B via the lis of equal indices;
            #   as there are at least 2 different values, at least two indices will get a desired value
            prev = equal_ind[0]
            old_first = B[prev]
            for k in equal_ind[1:]:
                B[prev] = B[k]
                prev = k
            B[prev] = old_first

print(A)
print(B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty, and improvements could be made, but here goes. 
Your requirements can be accomplished as follows:

```
val = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
A = [2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1,4,4, 2, 3, 1, 0, 4]
val_shifted = np.roll(val,1) 
dic_val = {i:val_shifted[i] for i in range(len(val_shifted))}
B = [dic_val[i] for i in A]
```

Which Gives the result that meets your requirement

```
A = [2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 0, 4]
B = [1, 2, 0, 5, 1, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 0, 5, 3]
```